# can't read from the webcam

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam-capture

For some strange reasons, the program fails to read frame from the webcam. It opens the webcam successfully though. I've searched for this problem and I found out a variety of solutions none of them worked with me. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int main()
{
    // access the default webcam 
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0); 

    // Double check the webcam before start reading. 
    if ( !cap.isOpened() ){ 
        std::cerr  << "Cannot open the webcam " << std::endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::namedWindow("webcam",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while ( true ){

       // acquire frame 
       cap >> frame;

       // Safety checking 
       if ( !frame.data ){ 
         std::cerr << "Cannot acquire frame from the webcam " << std::endl;
            break;
       }

       cv::imshow("webcam", frame); 

       if ( cv::waitKey(30) == 27){
        std::cout << "esc key is pressed" << std::endl;
        break; 
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the window before terminating the program.

[image]

I'm using Windows 7 ( dell laptop ). The code is compiled in the release mode linking against the .dlls. The OpenCV version is 2.4.10. 
In commmand prompt

```
cl /EHsc main.cpp /Fetest.exe /I D:\CPP_Libraries\opencv_2.4.10\build\include /link /LIBPATH:D:\CPP_Libraries\opencv_2.4.10\build\x86\vc12\lib opencv_core2410.lib opencv_highgui2410.lib
```

I have run the same code in ubuntu (dual boot alongside windows 7) and it opens the webcam but not through HighGUI and I got this error

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP
init done 
opengl support available
```

Any suggestions regarding this matter. After some diggings, [some ppl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447849/opencv-error-in-setting-resolution-with-c910) pointed out to `cmake`, therefore I need to reinstall the opencv and configure `cmake` properly. Are there any solutions for this problem without reinstall the library if this is really the problem for both ubuntu and Windows ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Follow the opencv documentation for VideoCapture heure : [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videocapture#videocapture). It provides a simple example for video capturing in C++.

There are some differences with your code, on is `Mat frame` is inside the loop.

Comment: Well, that code works, so if it doesn't on your computer it's either one installation which is defective, or your camera which isn't compatible with opencv.
You could also try other camera index: `VideoCapture cap(1)`. Maybe your camera isn't set by default for some reasons